# How to use Array or Dictionary in RealmSwift?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm tried RealmSwift.

And I save my model.
but RealmSwift does not support Array, Dic...
What can I do?

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DumbData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var myModel: [[String: String]]!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    let data = DumbData()
    data.myModel = [["asdf": "1234"]]

    let realm = try! Reaml()
    try realm.write {
        realm.add(data) // error. Realm Does not support Array, Dic...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array usually represented as [`List<T>`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html). This allows to handle [`many-to-many`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-many) relationship in Realm.

Dictionary is not supported by Realm. But it can be achieve with 2 classes and to-many relationship. For example:

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let stackOverflowQuestions = List<Question>()
}

class Question: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var message = ""
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships.
Like Swift’s Array, List is a generic type that is parameterized on the type of Object it stores.

for that if you want to use array via Realm

```
 var userMachines = List<Machine>()
```

and if you want to use it again as array after you saved your data in Realm 
use

```
func fetchRealmMachine() -> [Machine]{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let realmMachines = realm.object(ofType: UserSession.self)?.userMachines
    return Array(realmMachines!)
}
```

the result will return as array